# How to solder IC to Perf Board

Tags: prototyping

I just bought 5 boards from Allelectronics.com like [this](http://www.allelectronics.com/make-a-store/item/pc-2/solderable-perf-board/1.html). I decided to make a circuit that involved ICs. When I attempted to solder the circuit onto the board I realized that once you solder the IC on, as far a I can see, you can't wire components to the pins because the solder sticks to the separate holes. So my question is how do you solder components to ICs?  This should be easy I just don't get it because I am a newbie to prototyping.

Comment: You should invest in a solder wick to pull up that excess solder.   Then you can solder to a perf board no problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. How does that help me solder components together. My problem is the solder sticks to the holes instead of making a bridge between both holes. I want a bridge to connect multiple components to a pin of an IC

Comment: Oh I understand your issue now.  See answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a perfboard you typically either bend unused leads or use wire to connect the different holes and then solder the wire and the pins together at a hole.  You shouldn't use solder as some kind of interconnect trace like you're suggesting.

Here is a video showing proper perfboard construction.

[Video about perfboard construction.](http://makezine.com/2010/06/24/circuit-skills-perfboard-prototypin/)

Comment: Are there any boards you would suggest that make extra trace connections for ICs

Comment: You might be interested in this kind of "reverse" perfboard.  Every hole is shorted together and then you undo the connections you don't want with an exacto knife or something.  I've never used it but some people really like it.  https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8812

Comment: haw right, now it make sense why those through hole component have so long pins.

Answer (score 1):

There are perf boards available that have the holes connected together in the same pattern as the plastic breadboards, so you could easily transfer a breadboard project to a more permanent perf board design.

Vero Board has strips of copper connecting all holes in a row (or column, depending on how you hold the board).  You cut away the copper at a hole where you don't want a connection - Vero makes a special tool for this, but a 3/16" drill bit (or even an Exacto knife) will work.